# like 'Ignite With Cassandra' any tools available for Hbase

Tags: datagrid, ignite, in-memory-database, gridgain

Can anyone know like 'Ignite With Cassandra' any tools available for Hbase. eg:Ignite With Apache Hbase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can connect to HBase with JDBC, you can use Web Console and automatic RDBMS integration: https://apacheignite-tools.readme.io/docs/automatic-rdbms-integration

Comment: Hello Valentin 
as per your suggestion I have check it but get confused how to integrate Hbase and Ignite